# PY3: Flask-Socketio Alternative?

Tags: python-3.x, nginx, flask, websocket, uwsgi

All, I've been using Flask-Socketio extension with PY2.7, but recently migrated to PY3. There's no Gevent support for PY3 (yet), which breaks Flask-Socketio (the flask-socketio author is also waiting for this, see [current limitations](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)).

Is there any alternative to implementing websockets on flask running under NGINX/uWSGI with PY3?

So far: I've come across [this](https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets) server/client implementation that uses PY3's asyncio **with no gevent requirement**, but it's not for flask. Any advice  on how to embed this into the current flask server would also be great. More specifically the server implementation [there](https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets/blob/master/example/server.py) looks like:

```
start_server = websockets.serve(hello, 'localhost', 8765)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Not sure how to embed this into the main flask server script, make it work with uWSGI (which also supports websocket, adding to my confusion), etc. Any advice here?

Comment: Note that the project that you found is a WebSocket implementation. Flask-SocketIO does more than that, Socket.IO is a higher level protocol that can work over WebSocket but also over other transports for browsers that don't have WebSocket.

Comment: @Miguel, i knew you'd reply (huge fan of you work!). Yes, I am aware of the (flask-)SocketIO higher level functionality vs websocket only. As I mentioned in the question, the issue is that Gevent doesn't work on PY3, so everything that follows fails.. Any insight as to then Gevent (and Flask-Socketio) will be available on PY3? Would be great to return to that superior setup.

Answer (score 5):

The last version of flask-socketio  has support for PY3.  flask-socketio==1.0b1.

You can see it in Miguel's blog.

[Miguel's blog](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/flask-socketio-needs-your-help)

Comment: thanks, i've stopped tracking this after building a home-grown solution, i'll look into the new release.

Comment: @GG_Python - I am slowly pushed into that way as well. I feel that Flask-socketio is great however it has designed in a certain way.